# Not able to read application properties from Spring Boot in JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, junit

I have a `JUnit` test that I would like to run against a `REST` service which is already running on my machine at the specified port. Already tested the `REST` service with `Postman` and it works fine.

The plan here is to make the `REST` URLs configurable by externalizing them in a properties file. Hence I tried following and the `JUnit` class is not able to read the properties file value.

**StoreClientTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class StoreClientTest {

    private static final String STORE_URI = "http://localhost:8084/hpdas/store";
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }


    @Test
    public void testStore_NotNull() {
        //PRINTS ${name} instead of abc ?????
        System.out.println("name = " + name);
        assertNotNull(restTemplate.getForObject(STORE_URI, Map.class));
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        restTemplate = null;
    }

}
```

**src\test\main\resources\application.properties**

```
name=abc
```

Comment: Did you try to change the package in src\test\resources\application.properties ?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "change the package". Can you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### First, you need to create an application context configuration for the test

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class TestContextConfiguration {

}
```

#### Second, let your test class use this configuration

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestContextConfiguration.class)
public class StoreClientTest {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;
    // test cases ..
}
```